# How do I get box2d working with Maven?

Tags: maven, box2d

I am trying to use box2d as a dependancy with Maven.
I have googled "maven box2d" to receive the following link:
http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3558

It says to add the following to my POM

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbox2d</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbox2d</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>tetromi.net</id>
        <url>http://tetromi.net/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This then gives me an error in eclipse, because it can't find it.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal the repository is HS
you can download the JBox2D library [here](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/downloads/list)

and putting it in your own repository with the mvn install:file command line

- ## if you have the pom :

  mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/mly/jar -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=jar -DpomFile=path/to/pom.xml
- ## if you have not the pom :

  mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/mly/jar -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true